# How to get past month date using Javascript inside VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a bit new to Vue and was wondering how to get the the past month date: I have this code:

```
import SomeTable from "./table/SomeTable";

export default {
    name: "Cabinets",
    components: {SomeTable},
    data() {
        return {
            defaultColumns: [
                'id',
                'serialNumber'
            ],

            defaultStartDate: new Date(),
            defaultEndDate: new Date('2019-10-07')
        }
    },
    props: {
        startDate: {type: Date, required: false},
        endDate: {type: Date, required: false},
    }
}

</script>
```

And then I put `defaultStartDate` and `defaultEndDate` in the `SomeTable` element as follows:

```
 <some-table :start-date="defaultStartDate" :end-date="defaultEndDate" :default-columns="defaultColumns"></some-table>
```

Which then returns the correct startDate of today and also the set one. But when i try for instance to do something like this:

```
defaultEndDate: new Date().getFullYear() + '-' + new Date().getMonth() + '-' + new Date().getDate()
```

My local environment turns blank and get all sorts of errors. I think this is due to the fact I can't use Javascript in that place in Vue? But again I'm really not yet sure how Vue works and couldn't find much on it by googling. So how could I do this using Javascript or maybe even if Vue has a neat trick for it?

EDIT: 
the errors i'm getting are of the form:

> Error in data(): "TypeError: Date().getFullYear is not a function"

But then with all the javascript functions i used inside Vue. And also

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "endDate". Expected Date, got String with value "2019-9-5".

Comment: *"get all sorts of errors"* ... what are they? Error messages are extremely important and informative and also show you where in the code the problem lies. Include them with your question

Comment: @charlietfl you are right, but they didn't make sense as they were contradictory, one of them said the functions are undefiend and the other said that they got a String. So i thought they weren't useful.

Comment: Well they may confuse you but ignoring them completely is not the way to troubleshoot. In fact you seem to be misinterpreting their meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your codes, `endDate: {type: Date, required: false},` means `endDate` should be in Date type.

So you need to convert calculated value into `Date` like below:

```
defaultEndDate: new Date(`${(new Date()).getFullYear()}-${(new Date()).getMonth()}-${(new Date()).getDate()}`)
```

**EDIT:**
And you need to think of the month is January(0). By using the above method, you will get error when it is on January.
I think It could be better to use `computed` value like below;

```
computed: {
  defaultEndDate() {
     const now = new Date();
     now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);
     return new Date(now.toJSON().slice(0, 10));
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense and works perfectly, thank you. But since i wanted the past month, the `+1` is not needed as Javascript returns past month by default.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this